# GIT - two branches and order of merging to avoid conflict

Tags: git, github

Ok, so this is the scenario I'm facing. I'm working with two different branches and I'm editing the same file. Let's assume that first branch name is WORK-001 and second is WORK-002. Within WORK-001 branch I've provided changes shown below:

file: update.php

```
function test_update_7001() {
  dsm('work 001');
}
```

On the branch WORK-002 I've provided changes shown below:

file: update.php

```
function test_update_7002() {
  dsm('work 002');
}
```

I finished work on both branches, pushed changes and made two separate pull requests. The problem is that if the changes from branch WORK-002 are going to be merged first then the changes from WORK-001 won't ever be triggered (function test_update_7001() never gonna be run). These functions works this way: if 7002 is triggered first then number of this function is saved to database and next available number is 7003, system will never allow to run 7001. Of course I can provide both numbers the same, so it could be 7001 in both cases, but when the pull request is merged (doesn't really matter which one first) then conflict appear.

Is there a way to avoid conflict and force (somehow) the person who is responsible for mergeing to merge WORK-001 as first and WORK-002 as second so the order of merge is correct? Maybe some kind of sub branches?

Comment: Re-work your system or don't hard-code numbers / names that won't be valid.

Comment: The problem you're describing isn't the merge sequence, it's the test-run sequence.  You can merge WORK-001 into WORK-002 and just push that, then the history's guaranteed to be in the right order, but that still won't force them to run your tests in the right sequence, because git doesn't control your test harness or your corporate staff.

Comment: @jthill - That's one way of looking at it, but if they're using build automation that triggers runs off of commits to master (or whatever branch OP's merging into), then the merge order could matter.

Comment: I don't see the difference here, some human controls the sequence of test runs.  Setting it up so a single button does a merge and then runs a test harness isn't cause to expect the merge tool to dictate terms to the people who built and pushed the button, nor to interfere with the test harness. @MarkAdelsberger

Comment: Well, @jthill, it must be nice to be able to dictate procedure changes to your entire team.  Since not everyone has that luxury, I don't assume OP has it.  This is why I prefer to address problems as presented rather than try to reshape them into problems I like.  The problem as presented is that merging out of order would lead to a failure.

Comment: How to make git dictate procedure was what OP asked for.  Neither response, not  your ~don't do what you say you already did~  nor my "~you're asking how to make git control others' behavior, and no tool can do that~, can help with the problem as presented. @MarkAdelsberger

Comment: @jthill, you can keep twisting the words however you want.  The fact is OP is telling us that merge order matters in their environment, and you're only willing to respond in terms of the assumption that it doesn't.  My answer is based on how OP can change their **own** behavior - the one thing we can assume OP controls - to address this type of situation.  The fact that it may be too late for them to apply that advice in this instance is immaterial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to control the order in which the pull requests will be merged would be to not create the pull request for WORK-002 until after WORK-001 has been merged.  If this seems clunky, I would reply that it is a symptom of a clunky scheme of function naming conventions that allows the validity of one piece of code to depend on whether an unrelated change got committed before or after.

A few other notes:

*A premise built into your question is that giving them the same function name would cause a merge conflict.  This is (probably) incorrect.*

The default merge tool determines conflicts by where in the file (line number) a change is made, not by function names.  So my expectation would be that you'll get a conflict even if you give the functions distinct names (if the new functions are at the same position in the respective versions of the file), or no conflict even if they use the same name (if the new functions are at different positions in the respective versions of the file).

*The branch topology could arguably be considered to be the problem.*

Two branches independently rooted from master should be independent of one another.  If Change A has to be merged before Change B, even though in this case it's for a somewhat non-standard reason, you could interpret that as Change B depending on Change A.  In that case, the branch for Change B should be rooted on the branch for Change A, far enough down the branch that it includes the changes it depends on.

That last statement may be confusing, and without knowing more about the system you're using that requires `test_update_7001()` to be merged before `test_update_7002()` it's hard for me to clarify; so the "safe" thing would be to root WORK-002 at the HEAD of WORK-001.

There are two problems with that:

First, it doesn't force merging WORK-001 first; what it does is make it so that the WORK-002 PR would show changes *including* WORK-001, unless WORK-001 had already been merged.  If these changes are meant to be reviewed and accepted independently, that could cause problems.

Second, it sounds like you've already pushed the branches in their current topology, so rebasing WORK-002 (which is what you'd have to do) may be disruptive.

*If you really need function names to be merged to master in a particular order, then maybe assignment of the function names should be part of the merge process.*

But that's also hard to implement reliably, and in the end that brings me back to thinking your problem is a clunky system for identifying what functions can be run.

Comment: The system is Drupal 7 from the sound of it: [hook_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x)